# What type of window is acceptable for installation inside of a shower?

Tags: shower, windows, renovation

We have a bathroom renovation on our second floor that is wrapping up in the Chicago area.  We discovered a crack in the brand new window that was installed in the shower, so it will need to be replaced.  However, we are wondering if we should use the same kind of window, or if there is a better type of window to be used for showers.

Here is a photo of the newly installed window:

[image: Image of horizontal sliding window in shower]

As you can see it is a window with a pane that slides horizontally to open.  This replaces a much smaller jalousie window that was surrounded by a single row of glass block.

The primary concern is that the track in which the window pane slides to open is between ½" and ¾" deep, and seems like a place that water will collect.  Here is a picture of the track, with my hand for reference:

[image: Image of track in which window pane slides, with my finger in it, about a single knuckle deep]

My wife is particularly concerned about water pooling in this track and potentially running into the wall underneath.  I have been searching around online but am having difficulty finding any windows that are specifically designed for usage inside of a shower.  It is important we have *something* in place that can be opened, because that is critical for ventilation/cooling in the summer.

Is our concern about water collecting in this groove valid?  Is there *any* kind of large format window that is valid and safe for installation in a shower setting?  Or should we plan on just replacing this with glass block and another small jalousie?

Any advice is appreciated-- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the [weep hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZvPXNfafTM) is for, two inches to the right of your finger.

If it was done correctly, the sill is pitched and flashed to the building wrap, or has a drip edge.

It *will* eventually get gross in the track unlike glass block which doesn't have one.

Keep the room clean like it should be and there shouldn't be any problem. Looks nice. Even if glass block was 'better', I'd go with that.

Double hung windows (open up and down) don't have a track like that on the bottom on the inside. But if you're set on it being a slider, then there's going to be a track.

Comment: Looks like the left one is fixed. No reason it should be, presuming it isn't too close to an exhaust or something. If it is then you can't do a double hung.

Comment: Doublecheck with your AHJ, but where I am, shower windows have to be tempered glass.

Comment: Thanks, this was an very helpful answer.  For anyone like me, who was ignorant to weep holes, [here is a video that provides an overview of weep holes and how they work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZvPXNfafTM) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZvPXNfafTM